# Lombok fails, depending on the inner class declaration method at Java

Tags: java, class, inner-classes, lombok

I implemented a method of taking out at once because there are many overlapping inner classes.

method name is `getFee()`

However, depending on how the inner class is declared, we checked the case of Lombok failing.

I really wonder why there is such a difference. Do you happen to know the answer?

**Fail case**

```
package com.corp.test.block.dto.test;

import java.util.List;

import com.corp.test.block.dto.test.TransactionDataDto.Tx.AuthInfo.Fee; //<- This is Fail case!!

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;



@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TransactionDataDto {
    private Tx tx;
    private TxResponse txResponse;

    public Fee getFee(){ // <- This is Fail case!!!!
        return tx.authInfo.getFee();
    }

@Getter
public static class Tx{
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class AuthInfo{
        private Fee fee;

        @Getter
        public static class Fee{
            private String gasLimit;
        }
    }
```

**Fail Error (Lombok Error)**

```
 java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Getter
  location: class com.corp.test.block.dto.test.TransactionDataDto
```

**Success**

```
package  package com.corp.test.block.dto.test;

import java.util.List;


import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;



@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TransactionDataDto {
    private Tx tx;
    private TxResponse txResponse;

    public Tx.AuthInfo.Fee getFee(){ // <- This is Success case!!
        return tx.authInfo.getFee();
    }

@Getter
public static class Tx{
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class AuthInfo{
        private Fee fee;

        @Getter
        public static class Fee{
            private String gasLimit;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you think about creating different files for each classes?

Comment: Oh, don't worry about the motion problem. I just posted this question out of pure curiosity.